# Hiding features in eclipse update site from being visible to person who is updating

Tags: eclipse, plugins, categories, update-site

I have an eclipse update site with which I install my plugin features. 
I have a top category defined that displays the plugins to be installed under it. 
I do not want the plugin features to be displayed, just the top category. Is it possible to hide the underlying features? If not that could somebody suggest a work around?

Answer (score 0):

There is way to completely hide features in an update site.

However there is the convention that only features which are included in a category should be installed explicitly by end users. By default, the p2 user interface shows the feature grouped by categories, and in that mode, uncategorized features are not shown.

Still, users can see all features if they deselect the "Group by category" option in the UI.

Comment: Hi oberlies, sorry this was not the answer I was looking for, I was looking for something more that could be done from the Coder's side to resolver this. Your solution is something that the user has to do manually.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the above problem I found out by creating another overlaying update site and putting my original update site under it. I guess that is the only way to resolve this issue.

Comment: If this is the answer to the question, then I haven't understood the question. So for me, the question appears to be not useful, hence I voted -1. Others may find it useful and vote differently.